# query to display the name(s) of the alumni user (Role-‘Alumni’) from 2008 batch who has/have posted the maximum number of posts, sorted by name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE ROLE (
  id   INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE PROFILE (
  id     INT PRIMARY KEY,
  batch  VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE USER (
  id          INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name        VARCHAR(50),
  role_id     INT REFERENCES ROLE(id),
  profile_id  INT REFERENCES PROFILE(id)
);

CREATE TABLE POST (
  id       INT PRIMARY KEY,
  content  VARCHAR(4000),
  user_id  INT REFERENCES USER(id)
);
```

Write a SQL query to display the name(s) of the alumni user (Role-‘Alumni’) from 2008 batch who has/have posted the maximum number of posts, sorted by name.

I've tried this:

```
select user.name
from   user
       inner join role
       on user.role_id=role.id
       inner join profile
       on user.profile_id=profile.id
       inner join post
       on user.id=post.user_id
where  profile.batch="2008"
group by user.name
having count(post.content)=3
order by user.name;
```

I'm not able to put correct condition in the having clause.

Comment: Please share the code what you've tried so far. [What to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*

Comment: select user.name from user inner join role on user.role_id=role.id                              inner join profile on user.profile_id=profile.id                                                  inner join post on user.id=post.user_id                                                      where profile.batch="2008"                                                              group by user.name                                                                                            having count(post.content)=3 order by user.name;

Comment: I've redone your table descriptions into DDL statements - if they aren't correct then please edit them. Also, you have tagged it Oracle and MySQL - these are two different RDBMS; which one is this question for?

Comment: Iam sorry for tagging both oracle and mysql but the question is for mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35893b/7)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ROLE (
  id   INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE PROFILE (
  id     INT PRIMARY KEY,
  batch  VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE USER (
  id          INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name        VARCHAR(50),
  role_id     INT REFERENCES ROLE(id),
  profile_id  INT REFERENCES PROFILE(id)
);

CREATE TABLE POST (
  id       INT PRIMARY KEY,
  content  VARCHAR(4000),
  user_id  INT REFERENCES USER(id)
);

INSERT INTO ROLE    VALUES ( 1, 'Role1' );
INSERT INTO PROFILE VALUES ( 1, '2008'  );
INSERT INTO USER    VALUES ( 1, 'Alice', 1, 1 );
INSERT INTO USER    VALUES ( 2, 'Bob', 1, 1 );
INSERT INTO USER    VALUES ( 3, 'Carol', 1, 1 );
INSERT INTO POST    VALUES ( 1, 'Post 1', 1 );
INSERT INTO POST    VALUES ( 2, 'Post 2', 1 );
INSERT INTO POST    VALUES ( 3, 'Post 1', 2 );
INSERT INTO POST    VALUES ( 4, 'Post 1', 3 );
INSERT INTO POST    VALUES ( 5, 'Post 2', 3 );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT name
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         CASE WHEN @prev_value =  num_posts THEN @rank_count
              WHEN @prev_value := num_posts THEN @rank_count := @rank_count + 1
         END AS rank
  FROM   (
    SELECT u.name,
           ( SELECT COUNT( 1 ) FROM post t WHERE t.user_id = u.id ) AS num_posts
    from   user u
           inner join role r
           on u.role_id=r.id
           inner join profile p
           on u.profile_id=p.id,
           ( SELECT @prev_value := NULL, @rank_count := 0 ) i
    where  p.batch="2008"
    ORDER BY num_posts DESC
  ) posts
) ranks
WHERE rank = 1
ORDER BY name ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35893b/7/0)**:

```
|  name |
|-------|
| Alice |
| Carol |
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be this query

```
select user.name, count(post.id)
from user 
inner join role on user.role_id = role.id
inner join profile on user.profile_id = profile.id 
inner join post on user.id = post.user_id
where profile.batch = '2008'
and role.name = 'alumni'
group by user.name 
order by user.name ;
```

If you want only the users with max sum post the should be this

```
select user.name  from (
select user.name,  sum(post.id) totpost
from user 
inner join role on user.role_id = role.id
inner join profile on user.profile_id = profile.id 
inner join post on user.id = post.user_id
where profile.batch = '2008'
and role.name = 'alumni'
group by user.name 
having totpost = max(post.id)
order by totpost ) as mytable
```

Comment: It will show all the alumni users. But I want the users with maximum posts and also I do not want the count(post.id) column in the updated table, I only want the name of the users.

Comment: You want just one user ?

Comment: I can have more than one user if they  have maximum count equal

Answer (score 0):

```
select user.name, count(post.id)
from user 
inner join role on user.role_id = role.id
inner join profile on user.profile_id = profile.id 
inner join post on user.id = post.user_id
where profile.batch = '2008'
and role.name='Alumni'
group by user.name 
order by user.name ;
```

Comment: It will show all the alumni users. But I want the users with maximum posts and also I do not want the count(post.id) column in the updated table, I only want the name of the users. Other than that it is right.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit uncertain on whether content is a number of posts? Or is it a single post meaning there are multiple rows per user? Anyway, you could try the following which uses a join-construction and a subquery.

```
SELECT U.name
FROM User U, Profile Pr, Post Po, Role R
WHERE profile_id = Pr.id
AND role_id = R.id
AND user_id = U.id
AND R.name = 'Alumni'
AND batch = '2008'
AND content >= ALL (SELECT content FROM Post)
ORDER BY 1 DESC  (<---or ASC)
```

Comment: content is a single post meaning there are multiple rows per user.

Comment: Well in that case you could remove the last where condition and add:
`GROUP BY Po.user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Post GROUP BY user_id)`

Comment: @SamratPriyadarshi forgot to add the notification :)